# Сообщать Window, что в классе-сервисе были выполнены действия

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс, Например WorkService.
Есть окно WorkWindow с гридом Work-ов

В WorkService есть метод ProcessingWork, который вызывается извне принимает параметры, валидирует их и
записывает новый Work в базу данных.

Встал вопрос - **как дополнить метод ProcessingWork или доработать WorkService и WorkWindow,
чтобы после записи методом ProcessingWork Work-а в базу данных, сообщать об этом Workwindow.**
Окно, в свою очередь, будет обновлять грид с ворками и показывать, что появился новый ворк.

Comment: Непонятно: ваше WPF-приложение обращается к веб-сервису? Если нет, то уберите метки asp. Если да, то в любом случае оставьте одну правильную из трёх, потому что это _разные_ технологии.

Comment: убрал метки asp

Comment: [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) пробовали? А вообще, покажите пример реализации того, о чем речь. Можете создать минимальный пример на базе нового приложения?

Comment: Есть еще класс `Progress`, реализующий интерфейс `IProgress`, это по сути колбэк выполняющий свой код в том потоке, в котором он был создан. Примеров с ним много, он очень простой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант реализовать это через событие.
Если планируется закрывать окно, но не завершать работу программы. Необходимо при закрытии окна отписаться от события, иначе GC не сможет утилизировать объект вашей формы.  _workService.ProcessingWorkAdded -= _processingWorkAdded;

```
 class WorkService
    {
        public event EventHandler ProcessingWorkAdded;

        public void ProcessingWork()
        {
            //Некий код работы 

            ProcessingWorkAdded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    class WorkWindow
    {
        private readonly WorkService _workService;

        public WorkWindow(WorkService workService)
        {
            _workService = workService;
            _workService.ProcessingWorkAdded += _processingWorkAdded;

            Closed += _windowClosed;
        }

        private void _processingWorkAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Обновление грида
        }

        private void _windowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          _workService.ProcessingWorkAdded -= _processingWorkAdded;
        }
    }
```